# Starting tmux on Google cloud

Tags: python-3.x, linux, google-cloud-platform

**Goals**: I am trying to create a startup script on google which run tmux and also running python3 script on the tmux after start/reset the VM (virtual machine). My python script was a telegram bot script which response to the chat.

**My current condition**: I just know that startup script was run as a `root` so I run it using `sudo -H -u USERNAME tmux new-session -d -s SESSION-NAME`. It runs perfectly on startup script and the session was there when I make SSH connection to the machine. I am using debian 10 as OS and already install both python3 and tmux.

**Problem**: I want to run python3 code in the tmux session, so I add `"python3 XXXX.py"` at the back of the startup script. but it doesn't work as it should be. when I make SSH connection the session was not there. when I check the startup script - it was said that it was run perfectly but I cannot find my session and the script also did not run.

My current code:

```
#! bin/bash

sudo -H -u USERNAME tmux new-session -d -s SESSION-NAME "python3 SCRIPT.py"
```

Comment: I think your problem is **sudo**. Try using **runuser** instead. Also, put the session in the background.

Comment: Hi there, I will try the runuser. about the 2nd point what session do you mean?

Comment: You are starting a session in the **foreground**. The startup script will wait for that session to complete.